# Is there an equivalent to org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OLE for MacOsX?

Tags: macos

I have a plugin in eclipse which launches a media player in a view and plays supported media on Windows OS. But it obviously won't work on MacOSx, are there any supported libraries/packages/api's equivalent of org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OLE which can do the same job?

Thanks,
Abbas